# Find $a$ in a graph

Tags: circles, graphing-functions

**Question**

A circle of center $(-3 , -2)$ passes through the points $(0 , -6)$ and $(a , 0).$  Find $a$.

**What I know**

Well, you can say that these 2 points are equal distance to the centre, which means they are part of the circle.

***Problem***

But I do not know how to find $a$. Then I got no idea how to approach this question, so I do want some help please.

Comment: The distance from $(-3,-2)$ to $(0,-6)$ is the same as that from $(-3,-2)$ to $(a,0)$

Comment: so you are saying a is -6?

Comment: No, he's not. He's saying that the distance between the center and those two points is equal.

Comment: @scoopfaze okay. So then that means it will be √((-6 + 2)2 + (0 + 3)2) = √((a + 3)2 + (0 + 2)2) : distances from center to any point on the circle are equal.
a = -3 + √(21) , a = -3 - √(21) : solve for a and find two solutions. Right? Am I correct?

Comment: Right, @102152111, you are correct!

Comment: thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance between $(x,y)$ and $(u,v)$ is $\sqrt{(u-x)^2+(v-y)^2}$.

The distance between $(-3,-2)$ and $(0,-6)$ is $5$.

If $(a,0)$ is on the circle,

then the distance between $(-3,-2)$ and $(a,0)$ is also $5=\sqrt{(a+3)^2+2^2}$.

Can you solve for $a$?

Comment: yes! The answer is 1.58257569495!

Comment: actually, @102152111, as you commented above, there are two answers

Comment: Yes so the other answer is -7.58257569495?

Comment: yes (approximately)

Comment: Actually, I never thought I would ever answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Does this figure help?  The radii are the same.

[image]